# C++ create "linking" class for two other class via M:N relation

Tags: c++, class, relationship, class-relationship

Have an information system. It keeps track of employees and departments. An employee has a name.
The department has a name. Employee gets a salary that's related to his position in the department.
(Different people in a department can have different salaries, i.e. salary is a property of the relationship between
department and the employee!). There is also a class that allows the salary to be stored and linked to the
the employee with the relevant department.
 The application will allow you to independently create
employees and departments separately. When a person is employed in a department, a salary will be entered
and specify who will work where. All properties are enforced by the constables. In
the main feature of the program where I create at least 2 departments, at least 2 employees
and then guide them and give them salaries.
I know maybe you will say that one Employee couldnt be employed in more Departments but in this program yes, it is M:N. And can I ask how to add method that outputs all the employees who belong to the department with the given name (getemployee method).

Department.h

```
class Department{
private:
    std::string m_dname;

public:
    Department(std::string dname);

    std::string getName();
};
```

Department.cpp:

```
#include "Department.h"

Department::Department(std::string dname) {
    m_dname=dname;
}

std::string Department::getName(){
    return m_dname;
}
```

Employee.h:

```
class Employee{
private:
    std::string m_name;
    int m_salary;

public:
    Employee(std::string name);

    std::string getName();
    void addSalary();

    void addSalary(int salary);
};
```

Employee.cpp:

```
#include "Employee.h"

Employee::Employee(std::string name) {
    m_name=name;
}

std::string Employee::getName() {
    return m_name;
}

void Employee::addSalary(int salary){
    m_salary=salary;
}
```

Linking.h:

```
#include <vector>
#include "Department.h"
#include "Employee.h"

class Linking{
private:
    std::vector<Department*> m_department;
    std::vector<Employee*> m_employee;

public:
    Linking(Department* department, Employee* employee, int salary);

    Employee* getemployee(Department* department, std::string name);


};
```

Linking.cpp:

```
#include "Linking.h"
#include "Separation.h"
#include "Employee.h"


Linking::Linking(Department* department, Employee* employee, int salary) {
    m_department.push_back(department);
    m_employee.push_back(employee);
    employee->addPay(salary);
}

Employee* Linking::getemployee(Department* department, std::string name){
    for(int i=0; i >=m_department.size(); i++){
          //next code
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but still not fix my problem

Comment: Either each department have a container of employees working in that department; Or each employee have a container for the departments the employee is working in; Or you have both, for easy access.

Comment: Consider the indexes that would be used by a relational database to implement this relationship. You need a `std::map` for each of those indexes, or at least the ones that are relevant to your program.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So just Department or Employe, no Linking class like I have?

Comment: No there's no need for a linking class. You do need to have containers for all employees and departments somewhere of course.

Comment: A linking table is needed in a relational database, because everything is tabular. But C++ has vectors and pointers, so the `Department` class can simply have a vector of `Employee`.

Comment: Also, a linking table is generally only needed for many-to-many relationships.

Comment: @Barmar This is mean so, Could you show me how to link it for many to many?

Comment: And note the employee and department lists need to have some permanence guarantees or the pointers will be easily invalidated. For example, after placing all of the employee pointers in the correct departments, adding a new employee to a grand `vector` of employees could trigger a resize and leave all those outstanding pointers pointing at freed storage.

Comment: Should I read "M:N" as "many-to-many"?

Comment: @JaMiT Yes, it is

Comment: Does an employee who is working in two different departments earn a separate salary from each? If so, do you need to track the salaries separately? In order to do that, you would need a class that mimics the "linker" table used in a relational database. Otherwise, you are buying a "redundancy" problem, because data will be stored in more than one place in your program.

Comment: __Simplification tip:__ Try to get your [mre] into one file. Use `std::string` instead of `Department` and `Employee` if it does not interfere with what you are asking. If you do keep those classes, reduce their definitions to be as simple as possible so that they do not distract from the heart of your code, as in `struct Department{ std::string m_dname; };` While public data members are ill-advised in production, they are useful in side details of examples.

Comment: *"I ask how to add method that outputs all the employees who belong to the department with the given name"* -- The first step is to define how this is represented. Given an employee and a department, how can you know if the former belongs to the latter? *If you don't know this, shelve this question until you do. If you do know this, add it to the question. It's much more essential information for your question than your project description.*